# readdir function is not reading the whole directory on linux system

Tags: php, linux

On my hosting provider i have a directory called `hosts` that has  a structure like this

```
   .
├── hosts.php
├── ma_man_com.php
└── ma_women_com.php

0 directories, 3 files
```

the content of `hosts.php` file is this

```
<?php

$folderhost = opendir ( "./" );
$hosy = readdir ( $folderhost );
while ( $hostname = readdir ( $folderhost ) ) {
    echo $hostname.PHP_EOL;

}
closedir ( $folderhost );
?>
```

when i run `hosts.php` i get this output

```
 .
..
hosts.php
ma_man_com.php
```

so php doesn't show `ma_women_com.php` !

if i removed this useless line from `hosts.php`

```
$hosy = readdir ( $folderhost );
```

the output goes fine and  it can read `ma_women_com.php`

in addition if i removed on letter from one of the files like renaming `ma_women_com.php` to `ma_women_co.php`

then the output goes fine too

the strangest thing is that this behavior does not exist on my local host machine with windows 7 and xampp server

I know that the line that i removed from the code is useless and i can simply remove it and the problem will be solved but i'm curious why did this behavior happen and why it happened only on openshift linux servers ?

Comment: Why do you have one more `readdir()` outside of the loop?

Comment: Btw, you can also use [`scandir()`](http://php.net/scandir).

Comment: I've added it for debugging purposes and I'll remove it in the final code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code with the extra `readdir` skips the first entry read; since `readdir` reads files in arbitrary order and it is platform dependent what the order is, this means that on one platform you may skip `.`, on others a particular file; also note that the order of files may change if you change something in the directory, e.g. rename a file, which is apparently what happened when you removed one letter from the filename.

Comment: Yes , you were right on windows it skips `.` that i didn't notice

Answer (score 2):

It's because you call first read at this line:  `$hosy = readdir ( $folderhost );`

Answer (score 1):

Each call to `readdir()` reads one filename, and moves on to the next. So the "useless" line reads the first filename in the directory without printing it, and then the loop reads and prints the remaining filenames.

Answer (score 1):

That line is not only useless but it does read an entry that you are not using, so that it's why you did not see one of the files.

I am guessing that this also happened in your Windows environment, you just did not notice it because of the order of the files. I think that on Windows the first one (the one that you did not print) was in fact ".", your output started with ".."